# Sample Data Not Appearing During Runtime

Tags: wpf, radgrid, sample-data

I have a RadGrid with sample data being used. The problem i am facing is that, even after i changed the design time data context mode(that is, changed "d:DataContext" to "DataContext"), i am unable to see the sample data during runtime, though the filter symbol appears in the column headers during runtime. In such a case, when i click the filter symbol, no data is shown in the filter criteria either. What could be causing this issue, and how can it be solved? Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you are managing your sample data, you sample data may not be compiled into your application.  If you used Blend to create your sample data, click on the data source gear icon in the Data tab to show "Data source options".  Just check "Enable when running application".

If you used Visual Studio, check inside your csproj file and look for the tag `DesignTimeOnly`.  A file in the section will not be compiled into your application and therefore won't be available at run-time.  Otherwise it will appear as a normal `Page`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by unchecking and then re-checking "Enable When Running Application" on my sample data source.